# Is there any functional difference between return x,y and return (x,y)? Or is it purely syntactical?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, for example, is there any actual difference between:

```
def test1():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    return x,y
```

And:

```
def test2():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    return (x,y)
```

Comment: It is only a syntax difference. Just check `test1() == test2()`.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid constructors of the builtin [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) type, so, yes, the difference is purely a different syntax for the same thing.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: they are not constructors, they are literals.

Comment: good point! thanks for the clarification.